# Distribution of the number of outcomes from a Poisson distribution with two splits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I expect guests for my birthday party. Their number follows a Poisson distribution with some mean $\lambda$. With probability $p$ any arriving guest will be left-handed and with probability $1-p$, right-handed. Left-handed guests bring a present with probability $\alpha$, right-handed guests bring a present with probability $\beta$. How do I derive the distribution of the number of presents I will receive? Will it also be Poisson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with the coloring lemma for poisson point processes, you can see this problem in the following way: for each point of the poisson process, you are assigning  one of the possible colors $\{(L, 0), (L, 1), (R, 0), (R, 1)\}$ ($1$ is representing the guest brought a gift) with probabilities respectively $p(1 - \alpha)$, $p\alpha$, $(1-p)(1 - \beta)$ and $(1-p)\beta$. Actually, you are  interested in all points with color being either $(L, 1)$ or $(R, 1)$. So, the distribution of number of gifts is poisson with with mean $\lambda (p\alpha + (1-p)\beta)$.

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with this lemma, can you provide a reference?

Comment: You could read the section 5.1 of Kingman's [Poisson Processes](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=VEiM-OtwDHkC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=colouring+poisson&source=bl&ots=zXCzOUFx3M&sig=HqdXH3Pu2Tjgz2tY2Domqetifog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB58i6roHfAhUJhpAKHcT9D6sQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=colouring%20poisson&f=false)

Comment: Essentially, if for each point of a Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$ you assign color $c_i$ with probability $p_i$ the distribution of $N_i$, the number of points of color $c_i$ is precisely Poisson of mean $\lambda \cdot p_i$ and the random variables $N_i$ are all independent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of classification of a Poisson random variable. I can give you a hint about the distribution of the number of left-handed and right-handed people.
Let $L$ denote the number of left-handed people that will come to your birthday party and $R$ denote the number of the right-handed. What do you know about $L$ and $R$? Of course, $L+R$ is the total number of people who will come to your party and let us denote it as $N$. Knowing this, you can condition on $N$ and use *the Law of Total Probability* to get the joint distribution of $L$ and $R$. Then sum $L$ from $0$ to $\infty$ to get the marginal distribution of $L$ and similarly get the marginal distribution of $R$.

You can find that $L$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $p\lambda$ and $R$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $(1-p)\lambda$ and these two variables are actually independent!

As for the number of gifts you will receive, denote $L_0$ as the number of presents you receive from the left-handed, so that $L_0|L=l$ follows the distribution of $Binomial(l,\alpha)$ and use *the Law of total Total Probability* again.

I've been busy with some exams recently. Otherwise, I will present you with the full answer. Besides, you can turn to *Introduction to Probability Models* by Shelton M. Rose on Page 116 Example 3.23 for the solution of a similar question.

Comment: Thanks! Stepping through your algorithm, I don’t understand why we turn from Poisson to Binomial with left-handed people. You say that $L$ follows a Poisson distribution: can we apply the same reasoning again and say that the number of left-handed people bringing gifts is also Poisson with $\lambda_{L} = \alpha p \lambda$? I don’t see the difference between left-handed vs right-handed and left-handed-with-presents vs left-handed-without-presents.

Comment: @macleginn Please notice that I did not say $L_0$ follows a Binomial distribution. I said $L_0|L=l$ follows a Binomial distribution. These two statements are completely different. Actually, that's exactly how you derive the distribution of $L$ and $R$ i.e. $L|N=n$ follows $Binomial(n,p)$.